# How do we set up a @Get() method to receive and pass values?

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I created a controller for finding and returning products and keep getting the `internal server error` object returned to me.  I created methods in my controller and service that return the whole database object just to test my setup and was able to successfully request the data navigating to the api path as expected.  I can't figure out what exactly isn't working here in terms of if it isn't finding the object for some reason or if I'm doing something wrong causing it to break before it even attempts to search for it.  Here's my code.

***GetProductsController***

```
export class ProductDTO{
    cattegory: string;
    product: string;
}

@Controller('get-product')
export class GetProductsController {

    constructor(private dataService: GetProductsService){}

    @Get('find-product')
    getProduct(@Query()data: ProductDTO ){
        return this.dataService.fetchProduct(data.cattegory, data.product);
    }
}
```

***Service***

```
@Injectable()
export class GetProductsService {
    ProductData:ProductCattegoryItem[] = PRODUCTDATA; //imported mock data

    constructor(){}

    public fetchProduct(cattegory: string, product: string): ProductDataItem{
        return this.ProductData.find(a=> a.productCattegoryId === cattegory).products.find(a => a.productId === product) as ProductDataItem;
    }
}
```

This is the path generated in `Postman` after adding the keys and values I want to pass in

> http://localhost:3333/api/get-product/find-product?data.cattegory=golden_ratio_dividers&data.product=divider_03

I've been looking at all sorts of examples of `@Query()` but they're so basic they don't actually show anything, in fact a lot of the methods only `console.log()` a response as opposed to finding a piece of data in the database or something else practical.  I can't seem to find anything more in depth about it and have no clue as to what I need to do to get it to work.  Does anyone see the problem here?

Comment: If you add `console.log(data)` to your controller, before you make a call to your service and then your database, what gets logged out? I have a feeling your query params may not be coming in as you expect

Comment: ok I just did that and tried it in the browser and nothing is showing up in the console.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace at all? Something saying what went wrong?

Comment: no the call stack is empty, it just says `not paused`.

Comment: If there is no stack trace and you're still getting that error, all I'm able to do is ask if you have your code publicly available to try and reproduce the error. A GitHub link, for example

Comment: what would I need to include aside from what's already here?

Comment: A reproduction that someone can clone, install dependencies, run build, start, and then a command that reproduces the error

Answer (score 1):

HTTP GET requests never have a body with them, the data available is either found in query parameters or url parameters. With Nest you can access these values via `@Query()` and `@Param()` respectively.

Comment: ok I just switched the `@Body()` to `@Query('find-product)` and added the `find-product` path to the query in Postman and am still getting the same error.  From the examples I've looked at so far I don't see anything extra that needs to be done.  I messed with the api call and got a `404 error` as expected with non-existing paths, but going back to what I'm thinking is the "right path" gives the `500` error.

Comment: what does "eutger" mean?  is that a typo?

Comment: @Optiq "eutger" was most definitely a typo. Is both your controller **and** your route handler marked? And do you have a global prefix set up in your `main.ts`?

Comment: What do you mean by marked?  As far as the global prefix yes that's set.  As I mentioned in the post when I make a simple get request that returns the entire data object the call works successfully.  It's only messing up when I try to pass in data into it.

Comment: ooooh you meant "either" lol.  I had to ask though because there's people from all over the world on here, in fact I bet "eutger" means SOMETHING in somebody's language lol.